# Compare 2 different list and filter the first list

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Trying to achieve the below result but not able to find the correct process or code to resolve it. Please find any solution.

```
List ids = ['2330', '1111'];
List users = [{"id": ['1234','2330'], "name": "username1"}, {"id":['1111','2330'], "name": "username2"},{"id": ['3455','2331'], "name": "username3"}];
# I want the result to be like
List selectedUsers = [{"id": ['1234','2330'], "name": "username1"}, {"id":['1111','2330'], "name": "username2"}];
```

I tried this...

```
 List selectedUsers = users.where((u) => ids.contains(u["id"])).toList();
```

But that doesn't work...

```
 Result: []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is very confusing what you are trying to achieve, need more details

Comment: C i want to compare 2 list and filter the matched items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is slightly wrong. You are checking if ids contains the whole list u["id"].

Try this:

```
List selectedUsers = users.where((u) => ids.any((id) => u["id"].contains(id))).toList();
```

ids.any(...) takes a function as a test and returns true if any element of the iterable ids passes the test. Here, your test should return true if any of the id from ids appear in u["id"]. Now using this whole thing as your filter, you get the desired result:

```
[{id: [1234, 2330], name: username1}, {id: [1111, 2330], name: username2}]
```